# Coordinator layout and transparent status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I'm currently trying to use coordinator layout in order to collapse an image - in a theme with transparent status bar -, however three issues are bothering me:

1. When Activity is started, image is not being displayed behind the status bar (if I remove the coordinatorlayout, it works);
2. When I scroll up, I would like to change the status bar to a solid color, but a piece of the image remains showing;
3. After adding AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout the bottom of the image - with the same height of the status bar - get cut;

[image: image below status bar - even though it is set to be transparent in the theme]
*Image remains below status bar - even though it is set to be transparent in the theme*

[image: Status bar after collapsing - it should have a solid color]
*Status bar after collapsing - it should have a solid color*

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cover_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/rsc_character_details_cover_height">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"                 android:layout_height="@dimen/rsc_character_details_cover_height"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cover_wrapper"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="6">

           ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how I'm setting the status bar transparency:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's because a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is meant to be a wrapper for a `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problems with the image not being displayed behind the status bar and being cut off, anything that should be displayed in the status bar area should have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. ie. your `cover_wrapper` and `cover`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much

Comment: Is not the opposite? From docs: android:fitsSystemWindows

Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this view to leave space for the system windows.

Comment: @GPack some design library components modify the behavior of the flag https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

Comment: @karaokyo From reading the known post linked I understand that is modified only the first depth behavior, not the meaning of _true_ (padding to reserve space for system's decors) and of _false_ (not padding: the view will be behind the system's decors). I am wrong?

Comment: @GPack the problem is that I don't know what you're trying to get out of me. You cite some documentation, when in practice it works a certain way, and you can see that for yourself.